# Do you have to tip for late check out in US?

Tags: usa, tipping

I've read in hotels you should tip

- porters (taking bags),
- bag staff if leaving your bags for the hotel to take care of for any length of time,
- room service,
- room cleaners ($2-3), and
- reception staff if they went above and beyond.

#### Question

Is it necessary/expected to tip for a late checkout at medium-large hotels?

#### Example

If you ask the hotel to let you check out at 12-noon instead of 11am

Comment: I don't think so, if you tip the room cleaning staff, that should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not necessary or expected. But good-natured, tender hearted? Yes. If you can spare it, why not?

Answer from [Michael Forrest Jones
, Beechmont Hotels Corporation](https://www.quora.com/How-lenient-are-hotels-when-it-comes-to-checking-out-late-If-I-check-out-20-minutes-late-does-it-matter-and-why-How-about-an-hour-or-two-late-What-are-typical-late-fees/answer/Michael-Forrest-Jones)

> Every hotel sets its own rules on late check-out fees. Some (including mine) will give you so much extra time for the asking, some will let you stay into mid-afternoon for an extra twenty to fifty bucks, others will bill you for another night if you overstay check-out by five minutes.
>
> As to leniency toward guests who've stayed several days, maybe a week or two, yes, we're more inclined to go along if someone has spent a lot of money, has otherwise been a good guest, and can be counted upon for lots of revenue in the future. But no matter how lenient we want to be with anyone, mid-afternoon (3:00 p.m. if that's the hotel's check-in time) is the drop-dead, 'turn into a pumpkin', witching hour.

[Confessions of a hotel insider Jacob Tomsky](https://theweek.com/articles/469260/confessions-hotel-insider).

> Tip up front: Let the agent know you are serious immediately. Here's how I do it: I walk up, smile without showing teeth, give the agent my CC, drop a 20 on the desk, and say, "This is for you. Whatever you can do for me, I'd appreciate it." Boom. If I am after something specific, I will include that as well: "This is for you. Whatever you can do for me, I'd appreciate a room upgrade, late checkout, wine, whatever."

[Ultimate Late Check-Out Guide for Hotel Stays [2020] - UponArriving](https://www.uponarriving.com/late-check-out-hotel/)

> You can also consider tossing them a 10 spot or 20 spot but the fee for late check-out could be around $20 at some hotels, so you may be better off just paying that fee instead of going the pseudo-bribery route.

[How to Get Late Check-Out at a Hotel](https://www.tripsavvy.com/late-check-out-at-a-hotel-1862178)

> A discreet $20 bill passed to the front desk clerk could turn a no into a yes

[How-To: Score a Late Check-Out Time | Oyster.com](https://www.oyster.com/articles/how-to-score-a-late-check-out-time/)

> Sure, paying for a late checkout isn’t as ideal as getting the extra time for free but many hotels offer a half-day rate. [The Mirage](https://www.oyster.com/las-vegas/hotels/the-mirage-hotel-and-casino/) in [Las Vegas](https://www.oyster.com/las-vegas/hotels/) allows guests to stay until three p.m. for a $30 charge, and many find it’s worth it: The hotel rooms are far more comfortable than the airport gate.